# Compare two array of objects and push data into new array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here I m comparing b1 and b2 array of objects and adding data to new array b3 everything works fine, but in array b3 want to get array with id and without id only once in this case getting duplicate array elements in new array b3.

```
let b3 = [];
let idss;
let b1 = [
  { batchReferenceNo: '118', receivedQty: 1 },
  { batchReferenceNo: '120', receivedQty: 1 },
  { batchReferenceNo: '100', receivedQty: 1 },
];
let b2 = [
  { id: 1, batchReferenceNo: '118', receivedQty: 1 },
  { id: 3, batchReferenceNo: '120', receivedQty: 1 },
];
console.log(b2);
b1.forEach((bno1) => {
  b2.forEach((bno2) => {
    if (bno1.batchReferenceNo == bno2.batchReferenceNo) {
      idss = bno2.id;
      let c1 = {
        id: idss,batchReferenceNo: bno1.batchReferenceNo,qty: bno1.receivedQty
      };
      b3.push(c1);
    }
    if (bno1.batchReferenceNo != bno2.batchReferenceNo) {
      idss = '';
      let c1 = {
        id: idss,batchReferenceNo: bno1.batchReferenceNo,qty: bno1.receivedQty
      };
      b3.push(c1);
    }
  });
});
console.log(b3);
```

please help me out to solve this issue, thanks in advance.

```js
let b3 = [];
let idss;
let b1 = [
  { batchReferenceNo: '118', receivedQty: 1 },
  { batchReferenceNo: '120', receivedQty: 1 },
  { batchReferenceNo: '100', receivedQty: 1 },
];
let b2 = [
  { id: 1, batchReferenceNo: '118', receivedQty: 1 },
  { id: 3, batchReferenceNo: '120', receivedQty: 1 },
];
console.log(b2);
b1.forEach((bno1) => {
  b2.forEach((bno2) => {
    if (bno1.batchReferenceNo == bno2.batchReferenceNo) {
      idss = bno2.id;
      let c1 = {
        id: idss,batchReferenceNo: bno1.batchReferenceNo,qty: bno1.receivedQty
      };
      b3.push(c1);
    }
    if (bno1.batchReferenceNo != bno2.batchReferenceNo) {
      idss = '';
      let c1 = {
        id: idss,batchReferenceNo: bno1.batchReferenceNo,qty: bno1.receivedQty
      };
      b3.push(c1);
    }
  });
});
console.log(b3);
```

Comment: And what exactly is the issue or problem? Can you, for the provided input arrays, provide an example expected output?

Answer (score 0):

### If `b2` is a subset of `b1`

Contruct a `Map` out of `b2` array where **Map keys** are `batchReferenceNo` and **Map values** are the entire object. Now, loop over `b1` array and see if the current object is in the Map, if yes add the appropriate `id`, if no add an empty string.

```js
const 
  b1 = [{ batchReferenceNo: "118", receivedQty: 1 }, { batchReferenceNo: "120", receivedQty: 1 }, { batchReferenceNo: "100", receivedQty: 1 }],
  b2 = [{ id: 1, batchReferenceNo: "118", receivedQty: 1 }, { id: 3, batchReferenceNo: "120", receivedQty: 1 }],
      
  b2Map = new Map(b2.map((b) => [b.batchReferenceNo, b])),
  res = b1.map((b) =>
    b2Map.has(b.batchReferenceNo)
      ? { ...b, id: b2Map.get(b.batchReferenceNo).id }
      : { ...b, id: "" }
  );

console.log(res);
```

### If `b2` is not a subset of `b1`

Keep all the elements of `b2` and add elements from `b1` that are not in `b2`.

```js
const 
  b1 = [{ batchReferenceNo: "118", receivedQty: 1 }, { batchReferenceNo: "120", receivedQty: 1 }, { batchReferenceNo: "100", receivedQty: 1 }],
  b2 = [{ id: 1, batchReferenceNo: "118", receivedQty: 1 }, { id: 3, batchReferenceNo: "120", receivedQty: 1 }],
  b2Map = new Map(b2.map((b) => [b.batchReferenceNo, b])),
  res = b1
    .reduce(
      (r, b) => (!b2Map.has(b.batchReferenceNo) && r.push({ ...b, id: "" }), r),
      []
    )
    .concat(b2);

console.log(res);
```